# 2 columns followed by 5 columns (multiple columns) in a table

Tags: tables

I have a problem here. I need to make a table like this. However, none of the questions and answers on this site seem to help. I have tried experimenting with the code they gave (to fit my labels) and to no avail. Please, can you help me with this?

[image]

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. The multicolumn command might come in handy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You use `\multicolum{2}{c}{...}` to make a centered cell that spans two columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % provides the \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule macros
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l *{4}{c}}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Non-taxed}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Taxed}} \\ \midrule
Store type & Dec 2014 & Jun 2015 & Dec 2014 & Jun 2015 \\ \midrule
1 \\
3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a screenshot to your answer. Feel free to revert.

Comment: You can't imagine how excited I am right now! Thank you so much for this! Really helpful!

Answer (score 14):

Here's a variation on [TorbjørnT's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/533729/5001). (The main difference is in the use of  a couple of `\cmidrule` directives in place of a `\midrule` directive.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{4}{c} @{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Non-taxed}} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\textbf{Taxed}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
Store type & Dec 2014 & Jun 2015 & Dec 2014 & Jun 2015 \\
\midrule
1 \\
3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you as well!